# "find" and "ls" with GNU parallel

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, find, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use `GNU parallel` to post a lot of files to a web server. In my directory, I have some files:

```
file1.xml
file2.xml
```

and I have a shell script that looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

CMD="curl -X POST -d@$1 http://server/path"

eval $CMD
```

There's some other stuff in the script, but this was the simplest example. I tried to execute the following command:

```
ls | parallel -j2 script.sh {}
```

Which is what the `GNU parallel` pages show as the "normal" way to operate on files in a directory. This seems to pass the name of the file into my script, but curl complains that it can't load the data file passed in. However, if I do:

```
find . -name '*.xml' | parallel -j2 script.sh {}
```

it works fine. Is there a difference between how `ls` and `find` are passing arguments to my script? Or do I need to do something additional in that script?

Comment: you your tried running with #!/bin/bash -x that'll show you if your arguments aren't what you think they should be.

Comment: I'm always embarrassed when this happens, but when I tried to reproduce this issue the next day (and use the -x as suggested) I couldn't reproduce it and everything was working great. I've been able to use ls or find with success every time. I'm wondering if I somehow hosed up my environment and a log out/in cleared something up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used `parallel` but there is a different between `ls` & `find . -name '*.xml'`. `ls` will list **all** the files and directories where as `find . -name '*.xml'` will list only the files (and directories) which end with a **.xml**.
As suggested by Paul Rubel, just print the value of $1 in your script to check this. Additionally you may want to consider filtering the input to files only in `find` with the `-type f` option.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

GNU `parallel` is a variant of `xargs`. They both have very similar interfaces, and if you're looking for help on `parallel`, you may have more luck looking up information about `xargs`.

That being said, the way they both operate is fairly simple. With their default behavior, both programs read input from STDIN, then break the input up into tokens based on whitespace. Each of these tokens is then passed to a provided program as an argument. The default for xargs is to pass as many tokens as possible to the program, and then start a new process when the limit is hit. I'm not sure how the default for parallel works.

Here is an example:

```
> echo "foo    bar \
  baz" | xargs echo
foo bar baz
```

There are some problems with the default behavior, so it is common to see several variations.

The first issue is that because whitespace is used to tokenize, any files with white space in them will cause parallel and xargs to break. One solution is to tokenize around the NULL character instead. `find` even provides an option to make this easy to do:

```
> echo "Success!" > bad\ filename
> find . "bad\ filename" -print0 | xargs -0 cat
Success!
```

The `-print0` option tells `find` to seperate files with the NULL character instead of whitespace.
The `-0` option tells `xargs` to use the NULL character to tokenize each argument.

Note that `parallel` is  a little better than `xargs` in that its default behavior is the tokenize around only newlines, so there is less of a need to change the default behavior.

Another common issue is that you may want to control how the arguments are passed to `xargs` or `parallel`. If you need to have a specific placement of the arguments passed to the program, you can use `{}` to specify where the argument is to be placed.

```
> mkdir new_dir
> find -name *.xml | xargs mv {} new_dir
```

This will move all files in the current directory and subdirectories into the new_dir directory. It actually breaks down into the following:

```
> find -name *.xml | xargs echo mv {} new_dir
> mv foo.xml new_dir
> mv bar.xml new_dir
> mv baz.xml new_dir
```

So taking into consideration how `xargs` and `parallel` work, you should hopefully be able to see the issue with your command. `find . -name '*.xml'` will generate a list of xml files to be passed to the `script.sh` program.

```
> find . -name '*.xml' | parallel -j2 echo script.sh {}
> script.sh foo.xml
> script.sh bar.xml
> script.sh baz.xml
```

However, `ls | parallel -j2 script.sh {}` will generate a list of ALL files in the current directory to be passed to the script.sh program.

```
> ls | parallel -j2 echo script.sh {}
> script.sh some_directory
> script.sh some_file
> script.sh foo.xml
> ...
```

A more correct variant on the `ls` version would be as follows:

```
> ls *.xml | parallel -j2 script.sh {}
```

However, and important difference between this and the find version is that find will search through all subdirectories for files, while ls will only search the current directory. The equivalent `find` version of the above `ls` command would be as follows:

```
> find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.xml'
```

This will only search the current directory.

Answer (score 4):

Since it works with `find` you probably want to see what command GNU Parallel is running (using -v or --dryrun) and then try to run the failing commands manually.

```
ls *.xml | parallel --dryrun -j2 script.sh
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.xml' | parallel --dryrun -j2 script.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Neat.

I had never used parallel before.  It appears, though that there are two of them.
One is the Gnu Parrallel, and the one that was installed on my system has Tollef Fog Heen
listed as the author in the man pages.

As Paul mentioned, you should use 
   set -x

Also, the paradigm that you mentioned above doesn't seem to work on my parallel, rather, I have
to do the following:

```
$ cat ../script.sh
+ cat ../script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $@
$ parallel -ij2 ../script.sh {} -- $(find -name '*.xml')
++ find -name '*.xml'
+ parallel -ij2 ../script.sh '{}' -- ./b.xml ./c.xml ./a.xml ./d.xml ./e.xml
./c.xml
./b.xml
./d.xml
./a.xml
./e.xml
$ parallel -ij2 ../script.sh {} -- $(ls *.xml)
++ ls --color=auto a.xml b.xml c.xml d.xml e.xml
+ parallel -ij2 ../script.sh '{}' -- a.xml b.xml c.xml d.xml e.xml
b.xml
a.xml
d.xml
c.xml
e.xml
```

find does provide a different input, It prepends the relative path to the name.
Maybe that is what is messing up your script?